# sql query convert date to datetime with specific H:i:s

Tags: php, sql, date

Here is my db table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_table` (
  `start_date` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Year-Month-Day',
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`start_date`,`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

PHP

```
$q_date = '2013-02-24 01:00:00';
$t_time = date('H:i:s',time());  //Output = 05:42:37   Hours:Minutes:Seconds
```

SQL query

```
SELECT username WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date) >= '".strtotime($q_date)."'
```

As you can see..type of start_date column is date like "Year-Month-Day" and i need to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP with datetime like (start_date $t_time) so it will be like UNIX_TIMESTAMP(2013-04-24 05:42:37)

Is that possible ? Any idea please?

Thank you.

Comment: SELECT username WHERE start_date >= '". $q_date ."'

Answer (score 1):

You haven mentioned the database, but I assume it is mysql.

You said "As you can see..type of start_date column is date like "Year-Month-Day"" - but your start_date is a date in mysql date format. Conversion is matter of selecting data. Of course you could design you start_date as varchar (string) then you will be able to put any format of date you like. But until this is date you need to convert your date in selects to unix timestamp. Example conversion to and from unix timestamp.

```
select now(), unix_timestamp(now()),  from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(now())),
       unix_timestamp('2013-07-09 09:04:30'), from_unixtime(1373353795)
```

gives you

```
2013-07-09 09:10:15, 1373353815, 2013-07-09 09:10:15, 
1373353470, 2013-07-09 09:09:55
```

I am not familiar with php and do not know what format gives strtotime but should return same as now() returns (I can have other locales and your format can be different but always you can format timestamp as you want by

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

My addvice is to do one conversion and always to timestamp - faster:

```
SELECT username WHERE start_date >= some_php_conversion_which_produces_unix_timestamp.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really impossible to convert a DATE type to DATETIME because if Your DB table's column is in DATE then when You are inserting data in table then it will not insert time to Your DB. So using any of the SQL function You will not be able to find the actual information. You will get an wrong output.

So for getting proper output , if possible change Your field type to DATETIME. I think that would be the best solution.